# Reference error when searching on submit using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, referenceerror

I am having issues with search on submit using angularJS

Here is html, contained insied module and controller,

```
<form ng-submit="search()">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 typeahead-wrapper">
                <input type="text" ng-model="searchkeyword.keystring" id="searchField" placeholder="Type any keyword to search for a Masjid" class="form-control typeahead">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="goSearch" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
              </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </form>
```

Search function:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.searchkeyword    = {};
$scope.results = [];
$scope.searchkeyword.bylocation=2;
$scope.searchkeyword.lat=-1;
$scope.searchkeyword.lon=-1;
$scope.search = function() {
  /* the $http service allows you to make arbitrary ajax requests.
   * in this case you might also consider using angular-resource and setting up a
   * User $resource. */
  $http.get('http://localhost/json/search.php', { params: searchkeyword },
    function(response) { $scope.results = response; alert(response); },
    function(failure) { console.log("failed :(", failure); });
}}]);
```

As I submit, it gives the error

> ReferenceError: searchkeyword is not defined

Thanks for help.

Comment: $scope.searchkeyword should be in http.get

Comment: Thanks, removed that error, but not going into response/failure functions.

Comment: $http.get('http://localhost/json/search.php?params='+$scope.searchkeyword).....

Comment: You should not pass callbacks to http.get, it returns a promis so you have to use http.get().then(sucesscalback,errorcalback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$scope.searchkeyword` you are using only the `searchkeyword`

```
var url = 'http://localhost/json/search.php?params='+$scope.searchkeyword;
$http.get(url).function(response) { .....
```

Comment: Error: response is not defined.

Comment: Done it the sameway, but with callbacks as @MiTa suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change below code

```
        $http.get('http://localhost/json/search.php', { params: searchkeyword },
```

to

```
       $http.get('http://localhost/json/search.php', { params: $scope.searchkeyword },
```